# Thread.sleep() blocks the main UI thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, interrupted-exception

I have this thread:

```
private class MyThread extends Thread{
    public void run(){
        try {
            sleep(10000);
            Utils.stopTimer();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "interrupted");
        }
    }
}
```

And then I started the thread. But thread is blocking  main UI thread causing it to not respond to user interactions.

Comment: so what is your problem/issue? it works according to the Thread concepts

Comment: Use Thread.sleep(10000);

Comment: @Kirit Due to the unfortunate nature of `this.sleep` being an "alias" for the static method `Thread.sleep`, that will produce equivalent semantics. However, I do agree that explicitly calling the static method on the type is better form.

Comment: how are you staring this thread? Are you calling the start method or calling the run method directly?

Comment: I agree. Your question?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Call [`myThread.start()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#start()) and not `myThread.run()`.

Doing the latter *does not* cause the code to be executed in a different thread, but just calls the `run` method on the *current* (e.g. UI) thread - like any other normal method call.

---

Excerpt from linked documentation:

> `start` Causes this thread to begin execution; the Java Virtual Machine calls the `run` method [in the started thread] ..

Answer (score 4):

You need to call thread.start() to start a thread and when you call that run() method will automatically execute.

```
  Calling this thread will also blocks the UI thread, you need to call it Async Task or in runonuithread.
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to use `AsyncTask` or `Activity.RunOnUIThread` for this type of code to execute.